# How to test node module with Chai when the class requires a personal token as parameter?

Tags: node.js, chai

How can I make tests on my node module when is required to pass a personal token as parameter?

It is causing errors with Travis CI building process:

e.g.: `No 'your_personal_access_token' specified.`

`test.js`
e.g.:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var module = require('../index')({
'your_personal_access_token': <token>
});
```

And on module, I verify if the parameter was passed to the class when initialized, like below:

`index.js` e.g.:

```
function Module(config) {

  if(!config) {
    console.error(`No 'config' parameter specified.`);
  } else if (!config.your_personal_access_token) {
    console.error(`No 'your_personal_access_token' specified.`);
  }
...
}
```

I don't want to expose the token to public. I already tried to use `process.env.TOKEN` but it causes same error on Travis CI.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a token for testing purposes and put it that file.

If you do not want to include a token on the source code maybe you can receive the token as a parameter on the script and send it from the script running in TravisCI or from the script override the file to include the token.

I have never used TravisCI but I have used Jenkins and there is a part where I do that abut override some files to modify some data and I use the `sed` Linux command in order to achieve this. Hope this is useful to you!